# Lambda Function is not working in PriorityQueue Compator

Tags: java, debugging, priority-queue, generic-type-argument

I have created a Priority Queue in Java which organizes objects of type Fruit based on   Double values. I used a lambda function to compare the Double value differences between two Fruit objects.

```
PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Fruit, Double>> PQ = new PriorityQueue<>((a,b) -> 
(a.getValue() - b.getValue()));
```

I recieved the error message:

```
>error: incompatible types: cannot infer type arguments for PriorityQueue<>
>
>reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) E
>
>(argument mismatch; bad return type in lambda expression possibly lossy conversion from double to int)
>
>where E is a type-variable;
>
>E extends Object declared in class PriorityQueue
>
```

Note: I am using Java 9, so the use of lambda functions within the comparator argument for the PriorityQueue should be allowed.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `new PriorityQueue(Comparator.comparingDouble(e -> e.getValue())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Comparator<T>` lambda must return an *int* indicating which value is bigger, or whether they are equal. The result of subtracting two `double`s is a `double`, not the required `int`. If you were comparing `int`s, subtracting them is a cool "trick" that works almost all the time, but not with `double`s.

You can use `Double.compare`, which gives you the `int` you need:

```
PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Fruit, Double>> PQ = new PriorityQueue<>(
    (a,b) -> Double.compare(a.getValue(), b.getValue())
);
```

Alternatively, create a `Comparator<T>` using one of those convenient methods in `Comparator`, rather than using a lambda:

```
PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Fruit, Double>> PQ = new PriorityQueue<>(
    Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue)
);
```