# prog.java:59: error: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression ((p1,p2)->(p2.ratio-p1.ratio));

Tags: java, comparator, priority-queue, comparable

I am trying to make a priority Queue which contains pair of double and integer types but I am getting this error :

```
 -> error: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression PriorityQueue pq = new PriorityQueue
((p1,p2)->(p2.ratio-p1.ratio));
             ^
possible lossy conversion from double to int Note: Some messages have been simplified;
 recompile with -Xdiags: verbose to get full output 1 error
```

Here is the relevant code

```
class Item {
    int value, weight;
    Item(int x, int y){
        this.value = x;
        this.weight = y;
    }
}

class Solution
{
    static class Pair {
        double ratio;
        int index;
        Pair(double rat, int ind){
            this.ratio = rat;
            this.index = ind;
        }
    }
    //Function to get the maximum total value in the knapsack.
    double fractionalKnapsack(int W, Item arr[], int n) 
    {
        // Your code here
        PriorityQueue<Pair> pq = new PriorityQueue<Pair>
                                ((p1,p2)->(p2.ratio-p1.ratio));
                                
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            double x = (arr[i].value*1.0)/(arr[i].weight*1.0);
            pq.add(new Pair(x,i));
        }
        int s=0;
        double ans=0;
        while(!pq.isEmpty()){
            Pair pair = pq.poll();
            if(s+arr[pair.index].weight<W){
                ans+=arr[pair.index].value;
                s+=arr[pair.index].weight;
            }else{
                double y = (W-s)*1.0;
                ans+= y*pair.ratio;
                break;
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to take a lesson in correct Java style.   Your use of whitespace  before and after symbols is all inconsistent and non-conformant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lambda Function is not working in PriorityQueue Compator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65868782/lambda-function-is-not-working-in-priorityqueue-compator)

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 4):

The fundamental problem is that you need a `Comparator`, which must return an `int`, but subtraction between two `double` values returns a `double`. Java requires you to be specific here, because a return type of `double` doesn't conform, and Java will not coerce this automatically: a cast is required.

However, a `double` has a far larger range than `int`. So, for a very large or very small difference, the result will be wrong due to overflow or underflow.

Instead, in general, use [`Double.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#compare(double,double)) as your comparator for `double` values. In your case, as you're extracting values from an object, use [`Comparator.comparingDouble(pair -> pair.ratio)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingDouble(java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction)).

As an aside, even when comparing `int` values, it is better to not use subtraction, but instead use [`Integer.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compare(int,int)) (or [`Comparator.comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction))), because large differences (greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) can still cause overflow, yielding the wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter for the `PriorityQueue` constructor should be a 2 argument comparison function that returns an `int`.  But the lambda you supplied returns `p2.ratio - p1.ratio` which is a `double` ... since `ratio` has been declared as `double`.  A conversion from a `double` to an `int` is a lossy conversion: see the error message!

To satisfy the compiler, you need to perform an explicit cast; e.g.

```
(p1, p2) -> (int)(p2.ratio - p1.ratio)
```

**However**, while this addresses the compilation error, it is not a correct solution.  It gives incorrect answers in some cases.  Specifically, if the ratio difference is between `0.0` and `1.0` *exclusive*, the narrowing cast will truncate that value to `0` ... which incorrectly says that the ratios are equal.

See [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73001972/139985) for solutions that give the correct answer.